# how can i get the data contents from Android metadata (via an Exoplayer callback)

Tags: android, exoplayer

im using Exoplayer for android and need to extract/parse the "metadata" for an MP3 audio file.

ive got as far as getting that metadata, but am at a loss as to how i can actually parse/access that metadata. really appreciate some help.

the callback method im using that is delivering the metadata payload is below. the data type of the variable `metaDataEntry` is `CommentFrame`. im actually trying to get access to the "text" property so i can then parse it.

[image]

```
player?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
            override fun onTracksChanged(
                trackGroups: TrackGroupArray,
                trackSelections: TrackSelectionArray
            ) {
                for (i in 0 until trackGroups.length) {
                    val trackGroup = trackGroups[i]
                    for (j in 0 until trackGroup.length) {

                        val trackMetadata =
                            trackGroup.getFormat(j).metadata

                        val metaDataEntry = trackMetadata?.get(0)
                         <<<HOW CAN I ACCESS THE DATA in metaDataEntry? >>

                        if (trackMetadata != null) { // We found metadata. Do something with it here!
                            Log.d(TAG, trackMetadata.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

its cool i see i just needed to cast it.

`val metaDataEntry = trackMetadata?.get(0) as CommentFrame`